# Display a Google chart in a popup window + pass parameters to the chart through a hyperlink/button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization, bootstrap-modal

Can somebody please suggest a way to pass parameters (data) to the following google chart from the hyperlink(id="inline").To now I have hard-coded data in the function.plus I want to pop up the chart also in a j query fancybox (which is already done)..Please!! looking for some suggestions

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

      <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['columnchart']});
      </script>


      <script>

      function drawVisualization() {
         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],

        ]);
         var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('data')).draw(data, options);
      }


      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#inline").fancybox({
          'hideOnContentClick': true,
          onComplete: drawVisualization
        });
      });

      </script>
    </head>


    <body>
      <a id="inline" href="#data">Show Chart</a>
      <div style="display:none"><div style='height:400px;width:600px' id="data"></div></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what language you use to get the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about to get ugly...read on at your own risk !
Seriously, it's not a particularly elegant solution, but it might work for you (based on your specific requirements, which at the moment of writing are not very clear to me).

You could use a **[custom data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)** (let's call it `data-chart-data`) in each `<a>` element you want to display a chart and store there some serialized data.
(For my illustration I used a simple scheme: separating table rows with `|` and separating cell-data with `,`).)

```
<a href="#data" class="chartLink" 
        data-chart-data='"Year","Sales","Expenses"|"2004",1000,400'>
    Show Chart
</a>
```

Then, on the JS part, you need to pass the chart-data as parameter to the `drawVisualization()` function.

Accessing the chart-data (using HTML5): `aElem.dataset.chartData`
Accessing the chart-data (no HTML5): `aElem.getAttribute("data-chart-data")`

Unfortunately, you will need some custom function to convert the chart-data from string representation to a JS array. Here is my sample function that expects values of type integer (anything not enclosed in `"`) and string (anything enclosed in `"`):

```
function strToArr(str) {
    var arr = [];
    var rows = str.split("|");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [];
        var regex = new RegExp("^\"(.*)\"$");
        var values = rows[i].split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            var value = values[j].trim();
            row.push(regex.test(value) 
                    ? RegExp.$1 
                    : parseInt(value, 10));
        }
        arr.push(row);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Of course, you should modify this function to cover your needs.
In similar fashion, you could serialize the "options" and pass them as parameter to `drawVisualization()` too.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/LUK5T/)**.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that coming :P NP, always glad to help !

Answer (score 1):

There's three solutions: getting the data from the user, generating the data and visualisation from a server-side script, or obtaining the data after the script is loaded, via ajax.

- From the user.
  Add a form to the page. Using javascript events, when the user has entered their data, you process it and refresh the visualisation.
- From a server.
  Use a server-side language, e.g. PHP or ASP.net, to get the data from where it is - an outside source, a database... The server would obtain the data, then reformat it in the list of arrays Google chart expects.
- Via Ajax.
  You still need a server-side script to pick up the data where it is, but ajax results in more flexibility. A client script requests the data from the server. When the server sends it back, a callback function starts off the charting.

Answer (score 1):

Since Now **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**  is a popular front-end development framework,they provide a pop-window action in a nice [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) . Following will be the best solution (what I was expected) for my question.And I'm posting this answer because others can get a clear understanding about the solution for the above question. cheers! :)

**Inclusion of relevant CDNs**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Script for Google visualization chart**

```
<script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    function drawVisualization(year,value1,value2) {
         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],[year,value1,value2],]);
             var options = {title: 'Company Performance',hAxis: {title:'Year',titleTextStyle:color: 'red'}}};

new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(data, options);
          }
    </script>
```

**Bootstrap essentials**

```
    <body>
<h1>POP UP Google Chart Using Bootstrap </h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="drawVisualization('2004',50,35)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch Google Chart
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Pop Up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```